# If $(A-\lambda I)^{k_j} \vec{v_j} = \vec{0}$ then $(A-\lambda I)\vec{v_j} = V_j$ and $V_j\in \ker(A-\lambda I)^{k_j-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

In one book on differential equations and dynamical systems I read that if **(1)** $(A-\lambda I)^{k_j} \vec{v_j} = \vec{0}$ then **(2)** $(A-\lambda I)\vec{v_j} = V_j$ and $V_j\in \ker(A-\lambda I)^{k_j-1}$. But I don't see how (2) follows from (1). Can someone please explain?

Comment: I think $V_j$ is just defined to be $(A-\lambda I)\vec{v_j}$ and by definition, $\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k_j-1}$ is all vectors $\vec{v}$ such that $(A-\lambda I)^{k_j-1}\vec{v}=0$. Clearly $V_j$ is one such $\vec{v}$, since $(A-\lambda I)^{k_j-1}V_j=(A-\lambda I)^{k_j}\vec{v_j}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$(A - \lambda I)^{k_j-1}V_j = (A-\lambda I)^{k_j - 1}(A - \lambda I)v_j = (A - \lambda I)^{k_j}v_j = 0$$

Therefore, $V_j \in \ker(A-\lambda I)^{k_j - 1}$.